# Print text with ajax : KO when there is Line breaks (on Windows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some problems to print data containing line breaks with ajax.

On one side, I have a C function (getVersion) that reads a .txt file and send to the client something like `"{\"version\":\"<SOME_TEXT_WITH_BREAK_LINES>\"}"`

On the other side, I have a Javascript code that use ajax to call my C function and get the text in order to print it. Here is the code :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"getversion",
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function (version) {
        $('#data_tab').html("<pre>" + version['dataText'] + "</pre>");
    }
});
```

The fact is : On Linux, no problem, the text is printed on screen like I wanted to (Firefox).
But on Windows... fail : no text is displayed, when there is a line break or special char like '\r' (...etc), the code in my ajax success part is not used... (Firefox)

I made a test in my C function, with this text sent : `"TEST\\nTEST"` instead of "TEST\nTEST" it works on both Linux and Windows...
What can I do to have it working on both side, knowing that I don't know the text I have to send before printing it ?

EDIT :

With a `char * test = "TEST\nTEST"` in the C code, and a function to replace \n by \n, it works.
But when I put the content of my .txt file in a char *, and then apply the function, it doesn't.

Comment: I think you could replace all occurrences of "\n" with "\\n" before passing it to jquery. Use a regex replacement for this purpose.

Comment: I did not thought about regex, I'm going to try that, and keep you informed about the result

Comment: I made a function to replace all '\n' and '\r' by '\\n' and '\\r' but with no results.
I think there is a problem on top of that, maybe with the opening of the .txt file.

I tried a "unix2dos" and "dos2unix" too : KO